# When to use attribute for return-values in c#

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, return

Today i've seen attributes for `return`-values the first time (`IronPython` source code). But i don't get when to use it. So my question, what are the typical reasons to use attributes on return values?

For example:

```
[return: MaybeNotImplemented]
public object __eq__(object other) {
    object res = InvokeBoth(other, "__eq__");
    if (res != NotImplementedType.Value) {
        return res;
    }


    return NotImplementedType.Value;
}
```

Thank you all a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate time to use any attributes at all, anywhere, is when you have code that is observing these attributes.

With just a few exceptions, most attributes you can apply, either the ones in the framework or the ones you create yourself, are not observed by the compiler and thus does not in fact impact the generated code. As I said, there are a few exceptions but the attributes you show are not among those.

So, when does the attributes you've shown come into play? When there is code somewhere else that inspects this code and finds these attributes. Exactly what this code somewhere else *does* with the knowledge of these attributes you will have to go look at the code to find out.

So basically, there's no general answer to this question other than to say that somewhere there is a piece of code that knows about the `MaybeNotImplementedAttribute` and knows what to do with it.

For instance, [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) uses attributes to tag parameters, fields, properties, and return values so that ReSharper can give informed inspection results in the code editor:

- [NotNull] - The parameter/field/property/return value is expected to never be `null`
- [CanBeNull] - The parameter/field/property/return value is expected to sometimes be `null`

With this knowledge ReSharper can give you warnings, like here:

```
[CanBeNull]
public string GetName() { ... }

...

string name = GetName();
Console.WriteLine("Length = " + name.Length);
```

ReSharper will give a squiggly above under `name` in the expression `name.Length` since you're not guaranteed this code won't throw a `NullReferenceException`.

In the case of IronPython, which is a way to bridge the gap between .NET code and Python, I would expect that the code that manages this bridge looks at the returned value, the presence of that attribute, and flags the right circumstances with an exception to highlight the fact that you tried to compare two objects that doesn't know how to do that. This is thus an artifact of the actual implementation of IronPython.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation!